# How to kill a process/query in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, kill-process

I try to optimize a query. After every change, I must wait long time that the query is finished. It is really time consuming.
Is there any way to see the executed queries and kill/stop them??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the DB2 instance command line, you can type

```
db2 list applications show detail
```

In this list, you should find your process, note the application id.  You can use this command to kill it:

```
db2 force application (xx)
```

Where `xx` is the ID (or a comma-delimited list of IDs).

[Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001951.html) is the DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows v9.7 Information Center article on `FORCE APPLICATION`, and [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001958.html) is the one for `LIST APPLICATIONS`.   For both of these commands, you have to have the proper privileges on the database instance (most commonly `SYSADM` or `SYSCTRL`).