# How to cancel or terminate long-running query in DB2 CLP without killing CLP?

Tags: db2, command-line-interface, terminate

Assuming I started execution of an inefficient and long-running query in an IBM DB2 database using the CLP. *Maybe there are some terrible joins in there that take a lot of processing time in the database. Maybe I don't have the much needed index yet.*

```
# db2 +c -m
db2 => connect to mydb
db2 => select * from view_with_inefficient_long_running_query
//// CLP waiting for database response
```

How do I cancel the processing of this statement/query **without killing DB2 CLP?** I can do so by killing it, that is, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
db2 => select * from view_with_inefficient_long_running_query
^C
SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.  SQLSTATE=57014
# db2 +c -m
db2 =>
```

But is there another more elegant way? Perhaps another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>- shortcut? I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681668), but it doesn't talk about what I want.

Comment: It hurts when I do this.  I would drop view

Comment: What is the problem with killing the CLP?

Comment: @danny117 the view is just an example scenario. It has nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde inelegant, unclean exit, lost history, having to enter CLP again.

Comment: I know it's just an example.  I do like the timeout method below.  I think a  high level language or even higher lever broker processing the querries.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is not CTRL- to terminate CLP. Your option is to open another terminal session and use the LIST/FORCE applications, CTRL-Z the CLP to suspend it and use another CLP to LIST/FORCE or use a GUI tool like Data Server Manager to find the application and force it to terminate.

```
db2 list applications for <database>
```

get the application handle for the session(s) you want to terminate.

```
db2 force application ( application-handle )
```

see [LIST APPLICATIONS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001958.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-4-66) and [FORCE APPLICATION](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001951.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-4-37).

Comment: This requires me to open another terminal session, connect a second CLP and look for the "offending" database session. Can't I just Ctrl-(some key) on the first session to stop the query?

Comment: I suggest you look at the CLP section of the Knowledge Center:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc-gentopic2.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-0

Comment: Nothing useful there regarding this question. So what I'm asking for is simply not possible?

Comment: AFAIK, there is not CTRL-<key> to terminate CLP.  Your option is to open another terminal session and use the LIST/FORCE applications, CTRL-Z the CLP to suspend it and use another CLP to LIST/FORCE or use a GUI tool like Data Server Manager to find the application and force it to terminate.

Comment: I guess I'll have to accept that. Would you add your last comment to the top of your answer? The idea to Ctrl-Z to suspend the current CLP and start another one (to kill the first one's query) is a good idea. I can then exit the second CLP and return to the first one. It's the closest to what I want - no server configuration, no need for another terminal session, keeps history, kill query only (not whole process).

Answer (score 1):

Would you rather use a QueryTimeout configuration as in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0008809.html

This way your command would stop and report `SQLSTATE 57013`

```
-913 UNSUCCESSFUL EXECUTION CAUSED BY DEADLOCK OR TIMEOUT.
```

Comment: No, this requires server configuration. I'm looking for a CLP feature.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use CLP directly, why not go directly from the UNIX prompt?

```
db2 "select * from view_with_inefficient_long_running_query"
```

You can hit `Ctrl-C` to cancel your query.  The connection to the database is maintained by the DB2 Backend Process (`db2bp`), and you get all of the benefits of working in a UNIX shell – superior history, command pipelines, etc.

Comment: What about the `+c -m`? Do I have to type it for every query?

Comment: No, you can set use the `UPDATE COMMAND OPTIONS` statement (to change them interactively), and/or you can set the `DB2OPTIONS` environment variable for defaults.